# Does Visual Studio Emulator for Android allow creating directories

Tags: visual-studio-emulator

Tried to create directory as following:
File dir =

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
dir.mkdirs()
```

dir.mkdirs() always returns false for Visual Studio Emulator for Android.  The app with the above code works fine with Android devices. 
I also tried several other directories (e.g. a directory under the existing directory Download), and all have the same result.

Does Visual Studio Emulator for Android allow creating any directory at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I was able to get it to work by having these permissions setup in the manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I also hit the ">>" icon in the emulator and setup the SD card to point to a folder on my dev machine.